# How to create an array of arrays in scala

Tags: scala, testng

In Scala, I would like to create a [TestNG DataProvider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) that converts all the elements of an enumeration into an Array of Arrays where each element in the outer array is an array containing one of the values of the enumeration.

This is my first attempt, but it returns a Set of Arrays.

```
@DataProvider(name = "profileIdProvider")
def provideProfiles() = {
  for (profile <- ProfileId.values) yield Array(profile)
}
```

What I need it to return is something like this:

```
Array(Array(value1), Array(value2))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need arrays as opposed to Seq or List?  The example that you linked to is Java-centric, but in Scala most of what you'd do on an array you can also do on a list.

Comment: Hi Chris. The TestNG framework requires a DataProvider method to return either an Object[][] or an Iterator<Object[]>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@DataProvider(name = "profileIdProvider")
def provideProfiles() = {
  ProfileId.values.map(Array(_)).toArray
}
```

Not tested, but should work I think.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do (modified to use ProfileId.values of course):

```
def provideProfiles() = { 
    var returnVal = List[Array[Int]]()
    for (profile <- 1 to 5) returnVal :+= Array(profile)
    returnVal.toArray
}
```

Though I like @missingfaktor's answer more, of course.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Your solution works as well. If I needed to preserve ordering, this would be the way to go.